# How to reload/recreate sessionFactory bean in spring mvc without refresh entire webapplication context?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In spring with hibernate integration, i have following requirement.
I need to reload/re-create/refresh/update the only sessionFactory bean.

But while using

`((ConfigurableApplicationContext)ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext()).refresh();`

It reloads entire application context(all beans).

Could you please any one help me out to reload only one single bean based on some condition(like user selecting/clicking on some option at UI level)

Thank you..

Comment: How session factory bean you inject or initialize ? please post some code..

Comment: please check it once..<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.sf.orm.hb3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
 <props>
 <propkey="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>,etc..</props></property>
 <property name="mappingLocations">
 <list><value>/..../hbm/jobmaster.hbm.xml,etc..</value></list> 
 </property>
 <property name="namingStrategy" ref="namingStrategy"/>
 <property name="eventListeners"><map><entry key="post-insert" value-ref="envers"/>,----</map>
           </property>   
</bean>

Comment: <bean id="envers" class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
<bean id="namingStrategy" class="com.tlabs.ecm.BusinessProcess.utils.CustomNamingStrategy"/>

Answer (score 1):

It is not a direct answer, but I think reloading a new `SessionFactory` in the application context **without reloading other beans using it** will lead to serious problems. The `SessionFactory` is normally a singleton bean, and as such is injected in other beans using it only at context refresh. So even if you manage to put a new `SessionFactory` bean in your application context, no DAO will have knowledge of the change, and could even try to use a closed factory ...

If you really want to refresh the `SessionFactory` bean, you will have to :

- close the old bean
- create a new one
- carefully inject it in **all** beans (normally DAO) that use it mimicing what spring did at refresh time
- and all that should be "atomic" in the sense of no request should be treated until all beans are ready.

It is your application but all that looks error prone to me. At least be sure to let red flashing comments for maintainers ...

Answer (score 0):

buddy . have a try ~

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory defaultListableBeanFactory =(DefaultListableBeanFactory) xmlWebApplicationContext.getBeanFactory();
        BeanDefinition beanDefinition = defaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition("pooledConnectionFactory");
        beanDefinition.setBeanClassName(PooledConnectionFactory.class.getName());
        defaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition( "pooledConnectionFactory", beanDefinition);
```

Comment: thank so much you suggestion, i am able to reload the sessionFactory bean and i am able to get updated sessionFactory instance, but still it is reloading entire webapplication context, due to that i am losing     entire my previous session scoped data(objects) and due that i am getting NullPointer exception in further execution(flows). could you please suggest me what steps i need to do further?...                    thank you.

Comment: hi,buddy.  if click ui ,you change  sessionfactory one time,then  is it needed to change back in other situtation ?  if you need change back your sessionfactory .  I suggest you create two different sessionfactory .    thats  my opionion.